# How to lint .yml.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, erb, lint, rubocop

I'm trying to lint .yaml.erb files. [RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) seems unable to lint .erb files altogether, and although there is an [erb-lint](https://github.com/Shopify/erb-lint) gem, it appears to only support erb that renders to html, javascript, and text files. There's a linter for yaml as well called [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint). Is there a way to stitch these tools together or a way to configure them to handle this edge case? How do people normally handle linting files with multiple compilation steps like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reason you shouldn't be able to lint the Ruby parts of your `erb` file with `erb-lint`, but linting the YAML "template" is in general impossible. You could generate the actual YAML file by interpreting it and linting that though.